# Google Plus account blockage

Tags: google-plus

Is it true that Google Plus blocks your accounts (like Gmail) if you don't use your real name?

P.S. I don't like to use my real name on the internet; just the way I am.

Comment: Look here: http://infotrope.net/2011/08/04/google-plus-names-policy-explained/.

Answer (score 2):

> If your profile is suspended, you will not be able to make full use of Google services that require an active profile such as Google+, Reader and Picasa. This will not prevent you from using other Google services, like Gmail. Your profile can be restored by editing your name and submitting an appeal that will be reviewed by our team, as directed by on-screen instructions.

Here's the [official Google policy on names in Google+](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/answer.py?answer=1228271). (Actually, it is, by extension, their new Google Profile policy, as you can't have one without the other.)

Basically, you need to use your name as you are commonly known. My first name is "Albert" but nobody calls me that, so I use "Al".

Their rules:

- Your common first and last name in a single language script. Leave of the "Dr." and ".jr" and use one language
- Nicknames and pseudonyms need to go in the "other names" field
- No unusual characters (★, @, etc.)
- Your name must represent one individual. Entities should use the Page feature
- Don't use someone else's name
- Names can be changed only once every 30 days

Get all the details at their [official policy](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/answer.py?answer=1228271).

Comment: so they can block your gmail if they feel you not given your commonly known name?

Comment: No, haven't heard them blocking Gmail. Gmail doesn't depend on a profile.

Comment: To add to my original comment: I have two other Gmail accounts: One for a community organization I am a member of and another which is obviously not a real name that I use for my gaming activities. But obviously neither one has a Google Profile and, by extension, no Google+ account.